# TypeError: callback is not a function When using Nodemailer to send Email

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.googlemail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: '*******@gmail.com', //Gmail username
            pass: '******' // Gmail password
        },
        tls:{
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    let mailOptions = {
        from: ' "Nodemailer Contact" <********@gmail.com> ',
        to: '********@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Node Contact Request',
        text: '.......',
        html: output
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info)=>{
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        } 
        console.log("Message Sent: %s", info.messageId);
        console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
        res.render('contact', {msg: 'Email has been Sent!'}, {layout: false});
        //res.render('contact', {layout: false});
    });
```

ERROR:

> TypeError: callback is not a function
>       at Immediate._onImmediate (/home/sDesktop/EmailPage/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/utils.js:18:13)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:729:5)

Comment: Not that it matters much, but `return console.log(err);` are you sure this does what you think it does?

Comment: Much thanks. This issue has been resolved. I wrote this block of code in try block and everything is working fine now.